# Only variables can be passed by reference - array_walk

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I'm trying to build JSON from DB table, I need to use utf8_encode() before json_encode(). I go t this error.
Here is a code. What I'm doing wrong?

```
    <?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=MY_HOST;dbname=MY_DB;charset=UTF-8',  
    'MY_LOGIN', 'MY_PASS', array(  
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,  
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION  
    )  
);    

$stmt = $db->prepare(  
    "SELECT id,title,`fulltext`,catid,publish_state  FROM items WHERE id>:id"  
);  
$stmt->bindValue(':id', 2000, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->execute();  
$output_arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//FOR TEST ONLY
echo 'Output:<br />';
print_r ($output_arr); //prints OK if I remove line 21 (below)

//BEFORE ENCODING TO JSON I NEED TO ENCODE TO UTF-8...
$output_encoded = array_walk(utf8_encode, $output_arr);

//AND NOW I GOT ERROR:
//Only variables can be passed by reference in line 21

//MY NEXT STEP WOULD BE:
echo json_encode($output_encoded)
?>
```

Comment: `array_walk` return boolean

Answer (score 1):

If you'd fix your PDO connection string, you'd already be receiving UTF-8 encoded data directly from the database:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=MY_HOST;dbname=MY_DB;charset=utf8', ...
                                                       ^^^^
```

The charset is called "`utf8`" in MySQL, not UTF-8. Having set this `charset` parameter correctly, `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` will already return UTF-8 encoded data and there's no need to use `utf8_encode` at all.

---

As for your particular issue, you had the wrong syntax, it should have been:

```
array_walk($output_arr, 'utf8_encode')
```

Even that wouldn't have helped though, since the callback for `array_walk` needs to modify the parameter by reference, which `utf8_encode` does not do. You probably meant to do this:

```
$output_encoded = array_map('utf8_encode', $output_arr);
```

But even that wouldn't be correct, since `$output_arr` is a multidimensional array which would not be treated correctly here. And again, by fixing the PDO connection that's unnecessary anyway. In fact, do *not* do this when your database is already returning proper UTF-8, it'll just garble your data.

Comment: Weird nobody gave attention. Nice explanation deceze.

Comment: First method is not working. Strings are stripped on first not-ASCII letter, even after changing charset to utf8. I'll check the second method later. Thanks.